# Finding least number of moves

Tags: java, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming

I have the following problem statement:

> Given a number `n` (1 < `n` < 10^9), what is the least number of
> mathematical operations from the set (divide `n` by 2, divide `n` by 3,
> subtract 1 from `n`) that can be used to transform the number `n` to 1?

I have written the following code so far in an attempt to solve the problem:

```
while (n != 1) {
    if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 2 == 0) {
        if (n % 3 == 0) {
            n = n / 3;
            c = c + 1;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
            c = c + 1;
        }
    } else {
        n = n - 1;
        c = c + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(c);
```

But I dont get the desired output. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: The problem isn't with the code, it's with the logic.  Fix your logic.

Comment: Added the range of n.

Comment: can you help me with the logic?

Comment: So what is the 'desired output'?

Comment: It shouldn't be tough.  Trust me.  Think `while`.

Comment: This post is tagged with dynamic programming. Doesn't that suggest a good solution?

Comment: @clwhisk I'm working at it.

Comment: @clwhisk That's what i'm doing. When it's not a factor of two and three, you need to substract 1.

Comment: no, just count the number of times your would "need to" subtract 1

Comment: Would be nice to see a theoretical analysis of this. I'm pretty sure there is a better algorithm than "dumb" BFS or dynamic programming. The answers here don't really get to the point, unfortunately

Comment: @NiklasB. It doesn't seem like it can get much more efficent. If you reverse the operations so that you start from 1 and go to N (using multiplication, and addition instead), then it should be possible to see the similarity to trying to find the [shortest addition chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain#Methods_for_computing_addition_chains). This seems like it suffers the same kind of problems.

Comment: @Nuclearman: Even if that is so, I would like to see a theoretical analysis of the BFS + Pruning approach which does seem to work very well although I can't establish a better bound than O(n). It seems almost as if it has a polylogarithmic runtime

Comment: @NiklasB.: What is n in that case (as far as your O(n) bound goes)?

Comment: @Nuclearman the n from the question

Comment: @NiklasB. Ah yes. The issue is that you can't really avoid checking pretty much all of them (2N/3 or more), which can be done by using something like a prime sieve. The only way that might be able to do better be to use some math tricks like those used to improve trial division integer factorization from O(sqrt(n)), which is pretty much the same as O(n) in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to explore all possibilities.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> solve(int n, 
  ArrayList<Integer> moves, int bestMove,HashMap<Integer,Integer> memory) {

        if (moves.size() >= bestMove) return null;
        if (n == 1) return moves;
        Integer sizeOfPathN= memory.get(n);

        if (sizeOfPathN!=null && sizeOfPathN<=moves.size())return null;
        memory.put(n,moves.size());

        int size_1=Integer.MAX_VALUE, size_2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, size_3 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        ArrayList<Integer> moves3 = null, moves2 = null, moves1;

        if (n % 3 == 0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(moves);
            c.add(3);
            moves3 = solve(n / 3, c,bestMove,memory);
            if (moves3!=null)
            size_3 = moves3.size();
        }

        bestMove = Math.min(bestMove, size_3);

        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(moves);
            c.add(2);
            moves2 = solve(n / 2, c,bestMove,memory);
            if (moves2!=null)
            size_2 = moves2.size();
        }

        bestMove = Math.min(bestMove, size_2);


        ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>(moves);
        c.add(1);
        moves1 = solve(n - 1, c,bestMove,memory);
        if (moves1!=null)
        size_1 = moves1.size();

        int r = Math.min(Math.min(size_1, size_2),size_3);
        if (r==size_1) return moves1;
        if (r==size_2) return moves2;

        return moves3;

    }
```

**Explanation**:

`n` : n

`moves` : An ArrayList containing the movements. (for printing pourposes)

`bestMove` : value containing size of the minimal solution found.

`memory` : a HashMap containing the "state" explored previously and the length of the path.

If we call
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object[] sol=solve(10, new ArrayList<Integer>(),Integer.MAX_VALUE,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()).toArray();
    System.out.println(sol.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sol));
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-a));
}
```

The output would be:

```
3
[1, 3, 3]
1
```

Equivalent to `n-1, n/3,n/3` (@Tristan's best solution)

if we call it with `1000 000 000` as n:

```
30
[1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2]
55
```

If we call it with `11`:

```
4
[1, 1, 3, 3]
1
```

**EDIT:**
If only the number of moves it's needed:

```
public static int solve(int n,int moves,int bestMove,HashMap<Integer,Integer> memory) {

        if (moves >= bestMove) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        if (n == 1) return moves;
        Integer sizeOfPathN= memory.get(n);

        if (sizeOfPathN!=null && sizeOfPathN<=moves)return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        memory.put(n,moves);

        int size_1=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int size_2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int size_3 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        moves=moves+1;
        if (n % 3 == 0) size_3 = solve(n / 3, moves,bestMove,memory);
        bestMove = Math.min(bestMove, size_3);      
        if (n % 2 == 0) size_2=solve(n >> 1, moves,bestMove,memory);

        bestMove = Math.min(bestMove, size_2);

        size_1 = solve(n - 1, moves,bestMove,memory);


        return  Math.min(Math.min(size_1, size_2),size_3);


    }
```

Calling this method with

```
long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(
     solve(1000 *1000*1000, 0,Integer.MAX_VALUE,new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()));

    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-a));
```

Output:

```
30
24
```

Fast enough

Comment: How long does that take with `10^9`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider 30 sec in an i3 :)

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry. 20.

Comment: @Tyler do you need the sequence or not? It runs much faster without copying the `ArrayList`

Comment: No all I need is the size of the sequence i.e the number of moves. Can you optimize the code to reflect that?

Comment: i think you are not considering big-oh complexity of your code . @tyler is possibly trying to solve an online judge problem for which time limit would be around 0.2 sec on your pc

Comment: regarding this solution , i have posted same solution in my previous post .

Comment: @Tyler ok. I'll modify it.

Comment: this is why memoization exists. see DaoWen's answer

Comment: @Tyler Try again, 24 ms should be a reasonable time, don't you think?

Comment: @rpax can you please provide link , maybe ideone to your answer and show how it prints the actual sequence also , as i don't know to code in java .

Comment: @Tyler I'll post an entire example in a minute

Comment: You should be able to solve this problem just as fast and still get the actual path. I posted a solution in my answer that does just that, and it runs in about the same amount of time as your solution.

Comment: @DaoWen check the ideone. It's blazing fast. Getting the actual path http://ideone.com/o70wQ4

Comment: @rpax: You claim it is fast, but from what I see it could also be fast only for *n = 10^9*. What's missing here is some kind of runtime analysis

Comment: I am in fact reasonably convinced that it *is* indeed fast, although BFS should in general be O(n), so I'm interested in why that is :)

Comment: @rpax - Ah, I didn't realized you'd updated your answer to use memoization. I was just looking at the comments saying it took 30s to compute it with the path, and then you updated it and it took 24s to compute just the length. I thought that whole improvement was just from you removing all path-tracking stuff. Your answer is basically equivalent to mine now (you're doing DFS with recursion, whereas I did BFS iteratively, but they're basically the same thing), so it's no wonder they have about the same running times.

Comment: @rpax: yes , superb !

Comment: @aseem I am thinking in a new way to do it. Maybe an _non-optimal_  iterative solution, before starting the recursion? What do you think?

Comment: dharam's solution is far superior to this: much simpler and faster too.

Answer (score 7):

I think that Tristan is right—you have no way to know which operation will end up yielding the shortest path up-front, so you have to try all of them in order to get the right answer.

Typically, a brute-force solution like this would imply that the calculation will take exponential time. You start with *n*, then calculate up to 3 new numbers using your 3 operations. Then for each of those 3 numbers you get another 3, totaling 9. Then for each of those 9 you get another 3, totaling 27; and so on. You can see how you would quickly end up with a ridiculous number of possibilities.

However, your search space here is limited. Since all of your operations will cause the value to *decrease*, you will only encounter numbers from 1 to *n*, inclusive. This means it will take at most *n* operations to reach your goal of 1. There's only one shortest-length path to each number, so once you've found that path you don't need to consider any other paths you find that lead to that same number. If you keep a set of previously seen numbers, you should be able to eliminate a huge portion of your search space since you can throw out repeated results. (This is a form of [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).)

Here's how I would do that problem:

1. Create a `Set<Integer>` to contain previously **seen** values.
2. Create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to hold your **active** values. Each *key → value* entry's key would be a number in the path from *n* to `1`, and the value would be the number of operations it took to reach that number.
3. Put the initial entry *n* → `0` in your **active** map.
4. While your **active** map does not contain a key with value `1` (your target):

   1. Create an empty map to hold your **new active** values.
   2. For each entry in **active** *x* → *i* :

      1. If *x* is divisible by 3 and *x*/3 is not in the **seen** set, then add *x*/3 to **seen** and put *x*/3 → *i*+1 into your **new active** map.
      2. Do something similar for *x*/2 and *x*-1.
   3. Replace your current **active** map with the **new active** map.
5. Return the value *i* for the entry `1` → *i* in your **active map**.

There are a few things you could do to speed this up a bit more (e.g. break out of the loop immediately when you find `1`), or decrease the memory footprint (e.g. you discard sentries from the seen set if they're bigger than any of your active entries, or use a list instead of a map since all the *i* values for an iteration are the same), but this should be efficient enough to do what you need.

---

I've ported my solution to Java and posted it here:

http://ideone.com/qWt0LE

The output contains some timings. Note that the solution linked here uses a map for *seen* and a list for *active*. I store the previous number in the chain as the value for each map entry in *seen*, which allows me to reconstruct the chain at the end. In the output, 3 means *divided by 3*, 2 means *divided by 2*, and 1 means *subtracted 1*.

Comment: "you have no way to know which operation will end up yielding the shortest path up-front, so you have to try all of them in order to get the right answer." That sounds very unlikely. Do you have any justification for that?

Comment: @NiklasB. - Nope, just intuition. It kind of reminds me of the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), and reminds me a lot of several other optimization problems. Unless we can prove otherwise, we have to assume that there is no way to tell for some *n* which operation will yield the shortest path without trying all 3 options. Just look at Tristan's answer. Is there any way to tell for n=10 or n=11 what the best path is without just trying it?

Comment: @DaoWen: My initial intuition was that you can maybe solve the problem optimally for small *n* (below 10^6 or so) using DP and then use a greedy strategy for numbers that are greater than that. Turns out I can't find such a strategy, but maybe [the guys over at math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713698/minimum-number-of-operations-division-by-2-or-3-or-subtract-1-to-reduce-n-to) know more than I do, which is very likely :)

Comment: @NiklasB. - My solution uses memoization, which is the basis of dynamic programming. Each iteration works across *O(n)* elements in the active list, and there are a max of *O(log n)* iterations, meaning the total complexity is *O(n log n)*. I doubt you can do much better than that. I'm interested to see what the people over at the Math site have to say though!

Comment: It could actually be *O(n)* because you do only *O(1)* work per function call and you only have *n* different sets of arguments. But I guess using a simple BFS and pruning the values on the current level that are more than 3 times the minimum will get you a decently fast algorithm. Not sure if it's O(log^c n) though, but it might well be.

Comment: @NiklasB. - Ah, you're right! I really think there should be a tighter bound though based on the *O(log n)* bound on the iteration. However, nothing seems immediately obvious...

Comment: You only need to try the nearest smaller numbers divisible by 2 & 3 inclusive of the one you're testing (except for a few values near 1). See my solution.

Answer (score 7):

I believe question here is to just **count the minimum number of steps**, not the detail about steps, how to process it etc. So in that case below solution should be efficient and simplest one.  Bottom up approach in Dynamic programming .

```cpp
int getMinOperations(int n) {
    // Use this array to store the previous solved result.
    int dp[] = new int[n + 1];
    // base case, if it is 1, we do not need to do any processing
    dp[1] = 0;
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        // for the time being, let's assume we are getting minimum number of step by subtracting 1
        dp[i] = 1 + dp[i - 1];
        // if number if divisible by 2 let's divide it and compare it with the number of steps 
        // calculated in previous step, choose the minimum one
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], 1 + dp[i / 2]);
        // if number if divisible by 3 let's divide it and compare it with the number of steps 
        // calculated in previous step, choose the minimum one
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], 1 + dp[i / 3]);
        // At this step we have stored the minimum step to reduce the i to 1. and we will continue till nth value
    }
    // Returning nth value of array, as value at each index is the minimum number of steps to reduce it to 1.
    int res = dp[n];
    delete[] dp;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: this solution is far superior to the accepted one: much simpler and faster too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting case to think about.
From 10 you have a couple options:

```
10 / 2  = 5     1 move
5 - 1   = 4     2 moves
4 / 2   = 2     3 moves
2 - 1   = 1     4 moves


10 - 1  = 9     1 move
9 / 3   = 3     2 moves
3 / 3   = 1     3 moves
```

How about from a number that is two away from being divisible by 3?
Starting from 11 we have these options:

```
11 - 1  = 10    1 move
10 / 2  = 5     2 moves
5 - 1   = 4     3 moves
4 / 2   = 2     4 moves
2 / 2   = 1     5 moves


11 - 1  = 10    1 move
10 - 1  = 9     2 moves
9 / 3   = 3     3 moves
3 / 3   = 1     4 moves
```

Maybe this only works if the number you are subtracting to get to is ALSO divisible by 3? Who knows, goodluck OP.

Comment: yeah exactly. There can be so many cases. Do I need to check each and every one of them?

Comment: I think you might have to :P.

Comment: @Tristan Take a look at my answer.Maybe Now I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE** : this is NOT actual code , you need to think about corner cases , this is a pseudocode , which give **logic** about the algorithm .

This can be done recursively , but since `n` is very high , you need to memorize using extra space .

```
    fun(int n)
   {
        if(n==0) return INFINITY;
        if(n==1) return 0;  

        if(n%3==0)
        a = fun(n/3)

        if(n%2==0)
        b = fun(n/2)

        return min(fun(n-1) , a+1 , b+1)
}
```

Comment: This seems like the way you have to do it (check all possible paths and find the min). However, you don't initialize `a` or `b`, so this code isn't quite right. It should give the OP the right idea though.

Comment: The questioner's real problem is what algorithm should they use -- showing code (even if that is right ) may not help their original problem. In addition, this code (even if it is right) is NOT a good example because of space considerations.

Comment: This program will crush for even, n = 1e6

Answer (score 0):

Python implementations of two solutions using Dynamic Programming

1) Top-Down

```
def calculate(mins, n):
    if n<= 0:
        raise ValueError("input is not positive")
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if (mins[n] != -1):
        return mins[n]

    result = 1 + calculate(mins, n-1)
    if (n % 2 == 0):
        result = min(result, 1 + calculate(mins, n // 2))  
    if (n % 3 == 0):
        result = min(result, 1 + calculate(mins, n // 3))

    mins[n] = result
    return result

def get_min_step_memoization (n):
    mins = [-1] * (n+1)
    return calculate(mins, n)
```

2) Bottom Up

```
def get_min_step_dp(n):
    if n<= 0:
        raise ValueError("input is not positive")
    results = [-1] * (n+1)
    results[1] = 0 

    for idx in range(2, n+1):
        results[idx] = 1 + results[idx-1]
        if (idx % 2 == 0):
            results[idx] = min(results[idx], 1 + results[idx//2])
        if (idx %3 == 0):
            results[idx] = min(results[idx], 1 + results[idx//3])

    return results[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use memoization for speed.

Initialize your map:

```
n_to_steps = {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>1}
```

Now calculate. Do not calculate everything from 1 to n... instead:

```
def f(n)
  if n isn't a key in our map
    n_to_steps[n] = min(1 + n%2 + f(n/2), 1 + n%3 + f(n/3))
  end
  return n_to_steps[n]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `n= 10^9` points towards some logic , not just trying all possible cases and all permutations.
Here is what i got :

```
1 -> 0  
2 -> 1  
3 -> 1  
4 -> 2  
5 -> 3  
6 -> 2  
7 -> 3  
8 -> 3  
9 -> 2  
10 ->3  
11 ->4  
12 ->3  
13 ->4  
14 ->4  
15 ->3  
16 ->4  
17 ->5  
18 ->3  
19 ->4  
20 ->4  
21 ->4
```

So i think fornula is :

```
    while(n!=1)
    {
     if(n%3==0)
       ans += 1  and  n/=3 
      else if (n%2==0)
       ans += 1  and  n/=2
      else n--  , ans+=1
    }
```

*GIVES ANSWER FOR N = 1000000000 in 0.06 seconds .* http://ideone.com/0pfKoz

//
**PREVIOUS INCORRECT LOGIC :** (fails for n=30 easily as pointed by @Dukeling)

```
while(n!=1)
{
 if(n%2==0 && n%3==0)
   ans += p1 + p2   and  n=1  {where n = 2^p1 * 3^p2 }
  else if (n%2!=0 && n%3 !=0)
   n--
  else if (n%2==0 && n%3 !=0)
   ans+=1  and n/=2 
  else if (n%2!=0 && n%3 ==0)
   ans+=1  and n/=3 
}
```

**Please clarify if you have got the answer to this question , and try to see if my logic works .**

Comment: I believe 10 will give 4 instead of 3 for your code.

Comment: And what's going on here - `ans += n/3 + n/2`. Based on the others, I thought `ans` was the count, but this doesn't make it seem like it. And how did you get to `n/3 + n/2`? The closest thing that would make sense to me is `n = n/3/2; ans++`.

Comment: With regard to your edit - if `n = 30`, `n%2==0 && n%3==0` is true, but `n` can't be written as `2^p1 * 3^p2`.

Comment: @Dukeling  since there can be many cases like this , i feel it is difficult to come with an answer without considering all cases .

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However when n=11 how do i express it in p1 and p2?

Comment: @Tyler: i said that only when n is divisible both by 2 and 3 , and 11 does not satisfy that property .

Comment: @Tyler: forgot to do ans+=1 , on doing n--

Comment: It still returns 4 instead of 3 for n = 10.