# Primitive Calculator - Dynamic & Recursive approach

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have tried to solve the Primitive calculator problem with dynamic and recursive approach , works fine for smaller inputs but taking long time for larger inputs (eg: 96234) .

> You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following three operations with
> the current number : multiply  by 2, multiply  by 3, or add 1 to . Your goal is given a
> positive integer , find the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number 
> starting from the number 1.

```
import sys
def optimal_sequence(n,memo={}):
    
    
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    if (n==1):
        return 0
    c1 = 1+optimal_sequence(n-1,memo)
        
    c2 = float('inf')
    if n % 2 == 0  :
        c2 = 1+optimal_sequence(n // 2,memo)
        
    c3 = float('inf')
    if n % 3 == 0 :
        c3 = 1+optimal_sequence(n // 3,memo)
    
    c = min(c1,c2,c3)
    memo[n] = c
    
    return c

input = sys.stdin.read()
n = int(input)
sequence = optimal_sequence(n)
print(sequence)  # Only printing optimal no. of operations
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong in recursive solution as it works fine by using for loop.

Comment: You said it works fine for small numbers. What is the bug you encounter with big numbers?

Comment: It is taking long time

Comment: @Ben10101 if the code is working, but you need it optimized (as you said, running long time), this post is not for StackOverflow, but instead for CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is misleading: a process that takes a long time does not necessarily have a bug. You can assume a bug when the output is wrong.

Comment: That is not a bug, that is rather the nature of recursive programming. You can optimize it, but then the issue will occur on higher numbers again. Is this some kind of homework? Then the fact that recursion will take long on high calls would be the lesson you can learn here

Comment: I have already optimized it using memo object but it is not working by recursive approach, works fine by using for loop though .

Comment: The source of this problem? Please.  I think there is more info.

Comment: I have rewritten the complete problem statement above.

Comment: From the title, I thought this was about writing a symbolic antiderivative calculator :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider here. The first is that you always check if you can subtract 1 away from n. This is always going to be true until n is 1. therefor with a number like 12. You will end up taking 1 away first, then calling the function again with n=11, then n=10, then n=9 etc......only once you have resolved how many steps it will take to resolve using the -1 method (in this case c1 will be 11) you then try for c2.

So for c2 you then half 12, then call the function which will start with the -1 again so you end up with n=12, n=6, n=5, n=4...etc. Even though you have n in the memo you still spend a lot of wasted time on function calls.

Instead you probably want to just shrink the problem space as fast as possible. So start with the rule that will reduce n the most. I.E divide by 3, if that doesnt work then divide by 2, only if neither of the first two worked then subtract 1.

With this method you dont even need to track n as n will always be getting smaller so there is no need to have a memo dict tracking the results.

```py
from time import time


def optimal_sequence(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        c = optimal_sequence(n // 3)
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        c = optimal_sequence(n // 2)
    else:
        c = optimal_sequence(n - 1)
    return 1 + c


n = int(input("Enter a value for N: "))
start = time()
sequence = optimal_sequence(n)
end = time()
print(f"{sequence=} took {end - start} seconds")
```

also input is a python function to read from teh terminal you dont need to uses stdin

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter a value for N: 96234
sequence=15 took 0.0 seconds
```

Comment: The approach you used is greedy approach and dosen't give optimal no. of operations (Ans for n= 96234 is 14 operations ).

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough. Maybe have a look at this stack question as seems to be the same scenario and has a python solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40708569/1212401