# Optimization with recursion logic problem

Tags: c, recursion

I have this program, which needs to recursively find the minimal steps needed to get a number down to 1, when the only allowed steps are dividing by 3, 2 (only if it's divisible by them), and decreasing by 1. This is the way I implement it:

```
int escapingTime(int n) {
    int possibility1 = 0;
    int possibility2 = 0;
    int possibility3 = 0;

    if (n == 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        possibility1 = 1 + escapingTime(n / 3);
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        possibility2 = 1 + escapingTime(n / 2);
    }

    possibility3 = 1 + escapingTime(n - 1);

    if (possibility1 != 0 && possibility2 != 0) {
        return minimumOfThree(possibility1, possibility2, possibility3);
    }
    else if (possibility1 != 0) {
        return minimumOfTwo(possibility1, possibility3);
    }
    else if (possibility2 != 0) {
        return minimumOfTwo(possibility2, possibility3);
    }
    return possibility3;
}
```

I've tried changing the conditions and manipulating it, but I guess the problem is somewhere in the logic, which seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Does `n` have an upper limit? It may be easier to create a graph in reverse and then find the shortest path.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `n` will never be equal to `0`? Or negative?

Comment: Please also provide the value for a failing `n`, the expected outcome and what your program produces.

Comment: If the value will never be negative, then make all variables, including the argument, `unsigned` instead. And to safeguard against zero, change the first condition to `n <= 1`.

Comment: On each level of recursion you call that function up to 3 times. Is that supposed to be the case? If `n==6` you will both take the branch for `n/3` and `n/2`. You must be aware that this will surely lead to call branches for `n/2` and `n/3` in the next level of recursion. It should not matter if you divide by 2 first or by 3. In the end the number of divisions will be the same. You will just cause way more calls than needed.

Comment: See also: [Minimum number of operations (divide by 2/3 or subtract 1) to reduce n
 to 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713698)

Comment: [The same puzzle on codingninjas](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problems/min-steps-to-one-using-dp_920548)

Comment: Your function will work but it is extremely slow. escapingTime(1024) already takes about a minute on my laptop.

Comment: Instead of initializing the possibility counts to `0`, you should use `n` and simplify the logic by always returning `minimumOfThree(possibility1, possibility2, possibility3)`.  This will make the code simpler but not substantially faster.

Comment: [This iterative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951683/4593267) is simple and far more efficient than the recursive approach.